# Etherscan for private networks

Tags: etherscan

Is anyone aware of an Etherscan for private testnet?

I'm testing my own contracts, however, the current testnets seem to be under attack, so I've used my own private testnet to test deployment of my contracts, however, I would like to look at my contracts, and explore it.

If you're aware of an Etherscan that can work for private testnet, please provide the URL to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, There is no such block explorer for private networks. You can configure the private network with your custom configurations like (port no, rpcapi, rpcport etc) and so does everyone. It doesn't seem to a good idea to implement a block explorer for private testnet.

And why you need such explorer? You can get almost everything you need from your `geth console`. You can write simple javascript to get a block explorer like behavior. It depends on what you want to achieve, if you only want to access your contract, you can use Etherum-Wallet.